# Problemas al intentar enviar SMS en la APP

Tags: android, flutter, ios, android-permissions

mi idea es enviar directamente desde la app enviar SMS sin tener que realizar un launcher hacia el mensajero nativo de mi celular, lo cual en este momento necesito poder enviar un SMS ya preformado con variables que se traen desde la base de datos de firestore, que con antelación fueron ingresadas por el usuario en un formulario. Estonces mi problema es que no puedo realizarlo sin que me mande a presionar el boton Send, lo cual me gustaria que lo realizara en segundo plano.

```html
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ.SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
```

Estos son los permisos que ya coloque en el manifest

Comment: Lo que deseas requiere un servicio, y ya existe un servicio especial para esto: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager

Comment: No se puede. Sería un grandísimo agujero de seguridad poder enviar mensajes sin el consentimiento explícito del usuario. Si quieres automatizar el envío de sms's, necesitarás un backend externo.

Answer (score -1):

Actualmente ya existe un servicio creado específicamente para el envío de SMS desde una app, se llama **[SmsManager](https://Lo%20que%20deseas%20requiere%20un%20servicio,%20y%20ya%20existe%20un%20servicio%20especial%20para%20esto:%20https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager)**

Recuerda que aunque tengas definidos los permisos en tu Android Manifest.xml, algunos deben ser requeridos manualmente, este es un ejemplo para enviar un SMS desde una app Android.

```
import android.Manifest
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import android.telephony.SmsManager
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1212

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)      
        if (checkSMSStatePermission()) { //* Hay permisos envío SMS :-) 
            sendSMS() //*Envía SMS
        } else {
            requestPermission() //* No hay permisos envío SMS, se requieren.
        }
    }

    private fun sendSMS() {
        val smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault()
        val phoneNumber = "1234567890" //* Número de teléfono al que se desea enviar SMS
        val message =  "Hi from Stackoverflow.com"
        val SMSSentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext,0,Intent("SMS_SENT"),0)
        val SMSDeliveredIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(applicationContext,0,Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"),0)

        registerReceiver(object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(arg0: Context?, arg1: Intent) {
                when (resultCode) {
                    RESULT_OK ->
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Envió de SMS correcto",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               
                    else ->
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Error al enviar SMS",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }
        }, IntentFilter("SMS_SENT"))

        smsManager.sendTextMessage(
            phoneNumber,
            null,
            message,
            SMSSentIntent,
            SMSDeliveredIntent
        )
    }
 
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                sendSMS()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permiso SMS denegado",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    
    private fun checkSMSStatePermission(): Boolean {
        return (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    }

    private fun requestPermission() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,arrayOf(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS),SMS_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE)
    }
    
}
```

Comment: La respuesta no sería para el framework de Flutter, sino para android nativo.